# Signal not stable on UART Pins of BLDC motor controller PCB

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, noise, uart, grounding, brushless-dc-motor

I am designing a BLDC motor controller PCB based on STM32G030c8t6 microcontroller. But the waveform on UART is not stable. The dashed line is the ground on the following image, but some part of the the waveform are lifted from the ground at about 70mV to 80mV. Why could this be happening?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is your UART isolated relative to the PSU feeding the motor and the device at the other end? If not, some of the motor current might be flowing in the RS232/serial ground wire, causing the offset you are seeing.

Try monitoring the voltage between PSU gnd, and the UART gnd pin, to see if your problem is ground lift. (Use two probes in differential mode, and the shields only connected to each other to avoid additional groundloops.)

In any setting where there might be groundloops, I'd strongly recommend the use of galvanically isolate drivers. They are cheap and easy to use, with many offering built in isolated converters for the Tx drive.